# Tables with two or more foreign keys in Laravel

Tags: php, database, laravel, foreign-keys, eloquent

I have three database tables in my application. As an example, here is what I have now:

```
items TABLE: id, quantity, price, month_id (FK), department_id (FK)
months TABLE: id, month
department TABLE: id, department
```

I have already defined `hasMany` and `belongsTo` relations on the models. With these relations, I'm able to perform the query `App\Month::first()->items` to retrieve all first month items. However, if I want to query on both month and department, what is the best way to do it in this case?

I can certainly do it like this:

```
$month = App\Month::first();
$month->items()->where('department_id', '3')->get();
```

Is there more elegant way of doing this query?

Comment: Try this: `Month::with(['items' => function($q) { $q->where('department_id', 3) }])->first();`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can tell Eloquent to eagerly load needed relations to get better performance. You can do this by using *with()* method and defiling all needed relations - see http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading for more details.

Moreover, if you want to apply some additional criteria on loaded relations, you can do so using the same *with* method, but using different syntax to define relations and criteria:

```
$users = User::with(['posts' => function($query)
{
    $query->where('title', 'like', '%first%');

}])->get();
```